# Pass Inline Javascript function in to other inline javascript function as a parameter

Tags: javascript

single quote in the  string is creating a issue to execute the _gaq.push  function
Now i want to replace the single quote in the  text string  something like Replace("'", "\'").

```
<a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'XYZ', 'ABC', 'Music and fun daddy's child']);"  href="www.xyz.com" target="_blank">
Deal with daddy
</a>
```

Could someone please help me to write a replace javascript inline function and pass it as the parameter in to the _gaq.push function.

**UPDATE :-** 
 I am  using this script inside a Scripting languange supported by one content management system which does not allow to define the variable anymore.

So i need everything in a single java script called at onclick of the

Comment: Does the `_gaq.push` call have to be directly inlined to the `onclick` handler? It might be easier to wrap it in a function, and just have that wrapper function called via `onclick`.

Comment: How is this rendered? The ideal solution would be to escape the value properly when rendering the page.

Comment: View my posted answer

Comment: You cannot do that with javascript when it's already a syntax error in the first place. How do you create that html markup? If it's handwritten just add the missing backslash, if it's dynamically generated at the server please [post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18059233/edit) that code and add a tag for your serverside language.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do this really is set a variable outside of the onclick.

```
var description = "Music and fun daddy's child".replace("'", "\'");

<a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'XYZ', 'ABC', '" + description + "']);"  href="www.xyz.com" target="_blank">
Deal with daddy
</a>
```

Comment: You are correct guys , but here is a challenge .Scripting langauge which i am using does not allow me to define any variable. It is  content management system supported scripting langaunge.

Comment: How do you use that variable in the HTML markup? Looks quite invalid currently.

Answer (score 0):

Before passing the `'Music and fun daddy's child'` value to the anchor tag `onclick` function, you have to get that value and use the `.indexOf()` method to find if there are any single quotes (`'`).
If found you have to replace them with `\'` by using the `.replace()` method

**i.e.**

```
var str = "Music and fun daddy's child";
var n = str.indexOf("'");
if(n >= 0){
var n = str.replace("'","\\'");
  alert(n);
}
```

Then pass that value to the function like

```
<a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'XYZ', 'ABC', '"+n+"']);"  href="www.xyz.com" target="_blank">
   Deal with daddy
</a>
```

Comment: [`String.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains) is currently unsupported in any browser other than Firefox. I tried it myself in Chrome 28. You should be using [`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), which has been supported [as far back as IE6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/53xtt423(v=vs.94).aspx) (if not further).

Comment: Editing it without informing you wouldn't have let you know that `.contains()` is unsupported. I went ahead and edited it for you, but for such a drastic change as that, you are welcome to edit it yourself instead of leaving the onus on others, so that you can review your answer in light of the change to make sure it still makes sense the way you thought about it.

Comment: @ajp15243 Edited myself, ThankQ for your feedback.

Comment: You are correct guys , but here is a challenge .Scripting langauge which i am using does not allow me to define any variable. It is  content management system supported scripting langaunge.

Comment: @user584 then before pass this var to your function you can replace in your code language Java/c# any...